# Why the validation loss is 0 even if accuracy not 100%?

Tags: classification, cnn, loss-function

I am training a CNN to perform a binary classification and at some point I get validation loss 0, however the validation accuracy is 84.5%. Why does this happen? I use binary_crossentropy as loss function and sigmoid as activation in the last layer.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like an error.

Comment: Are you sure that the validation loss that's reported as 0 is calculated on the entire validation set (and not on some subset)?

Comment: Could you paste your **fit** method? Maybe you are using validation_split

Comment: @ItamarMushkin i think you might be right, I have checked and the number of samples in the validation set is not perfectly divided by the batch size. I am using this: validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size, where nb_validation_samples=260 and batch_size=32. However, isn't the accuracy computed on the same samples as the loss?

Comment: @10xAI this is my fit method     hist = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
        callbacks=keras_callbacks)

Comment: I'm no keras expert, but I know that I never know what samples are the loss calculated on. This is why I always trust metrics (including binary_log_loss, for that matter) that are calculated after training.

Comment: Can you add the full code/Link, seems everything is good with this much of info